# How do I permanantly add a path to the g++ compiler?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I'm currently using a non standard c++ library in my programs, but linking the library everytime I run the code is getting annoying. Right now I'm using

```
c++ file.cpp -o file -L/path/to/lib -lLibName
```

I tried the following:

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/path/to/lib
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

but it neither solved the issue nor gave me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should look into CMake or any other build system for that matter

Comment: "Include path" != "Library path"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option would be use a makefile and run [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

You can edit the makefile to add the necessary compiler and linker options.

GNU Make uses many [implicit variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html). For your use case, the contents of the Makefile can be as simple as:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall
LDFLAGS = -L/path/to/lib -lLibName
```